# Git checkout specific file with ignore case

Tags: git

I want to make an automated checkout on a specific file with git.

For example:

```bash
git checkout 'RELEASENOTES.MD'
git checkout 'RELEASENOTES.md'
git checkout 'releasenotes.md'
```

But git is case-sensitive during the checkout... how to avoid it?

I dont want to checkout the whole repo... that takes during the checkouts too long.

Comment: Do you know the actual casing of the target file? Is it changing from commit to commit? Why if you're going to automate the checkout, why not just use the correct casing in the automation script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a script. Something like

```
#!/bin/bash

git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | grep -i $1 | while read file; do
    git checkout -- $file
done
```

Then, run `my-script somefile.txt`. That should work.